# Drupal 8 store node data alternative in store

Tags: php, elasticsearch, drupal, drupal-8

Don't have much of a code example just a question and an idea.

I want to be able to save node data (from content creation) into an in-house datastore using elastic DSL queries.

I have heard/seen slides about Drupal supporting MongoDB to extent which makes me think this is doable. Even if I have to override the NodeForm/save handler is there a way to manipulate the node entities for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly doable. We're using Elasticsarch in all our Drupal projects, mainly to use it for full-text searches. Every node is saved twice:

- one time in Drupal's database, this is the node use in every code line
- one time in an Elasticsearch index, this one is never "used" ; we use full-text searches to find nids, then we retrieve the full object in Drupal DB

You can use `elasticsearch_connector` module to get an easy-to-use manager like this:

```
$cluster = Cluster::load('ES-CLUSTER');
$clientManager = \Drupal::service('elasticsearch_connector.client_manager');
$client = $clientManager->getClientForCluster($this->cluster);
```

And then use this client to manage your nodes' indexation:

```
function hook_node_insert($node) {
  $client->insert($node);
}
function hook_node_update($node) {
  $client->update($node);
}
function hook_node_insert($node) {
  $client->delete($node);
}
```

The biggest part of the work is to create your mapping (if you want it to be manageable via a module), but here again `elasticsearch_connector` will give you tools for it:

```
$client->indices()->putMapping($params); 
$client->indices()->putSettings($params); 
$client->search($params);
```

Comment: Downside is the hooks in either suggestion are part of Drupal 8 :/

Comment: Hum, haven't you tagged and entitled your question with [tag:drupal-8]?

Comment: I mean aren't sorry

Comment: Ah, but they are part of Drupal 8.
 [They are documented under the hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x). they

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to have them saved twice. First, to have normal nodes and second by using those "elastic DSL queries" (not sure what they are).

Anyway, you could use [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.9.x) which would be called every time normal node saving will be done and there you can place your code for that "elastic DSL" saves. From that hook you can access data that will be saved but you can also alter them if you need to do that.

Comment: Downside is the hooks in either suggestion are part of Drupal 8 :/

Comment: @Kal I don't know what you mean. The question is tagged for Drupal 8. If you are using Drupal 7, [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) is used from Drupal 7 too.

Comment: And yes, those hooks are used by Drupal 8, as the comment for the other answer said.